# Error: Could not find or load main class with OpenJDK and Oracle Java on CentOS 7

Tags: linux, centos, java, centos-7, jdk

On CentOS 7.2 Linux I have successfully downloaded and installed [Oracle Java](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/) with:

```
# rpm -Uvh jdk-8u91-linux-x64.rpm
```

Also there is already OpenJDK installed:

```
# rpm -qa | grep -i jdk
java-1.8.0-openjdk-headless-1.8.0.91-0.b14.el7_2.x86_64
java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.91-0.b14.el7_2.x86_64
jdk1.8.0_91-1.8.0_91-fcs.x86_64
```

I can switch between the 2 using this command:

```
# alternatives --config java

There are 2 programs which provide 'java'.

  Selection    Command
-----------------------------------------------
*  1 /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.91-0.b14.el7_2.x86_64/jre/bin/java
 + 2 /usr/java/jdk1.8.0_91/jre/bin/java

Enter to keep the current selection[+], or type selection number:
```

And see the version with:

```
# java -version
java version "1.8.0_91"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_91-b14)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.91-b14, mixed mode)

# javac -version
javac 1.8.0_91
```

Now to my problem please -

I create a simple java file named `TheClassName.java`:

```
package thepackagename;

public class TheClassName {
        public static final void main(String[] args)  {
                System.out.println("Hello World!");
        }
}
```

After successfully compiling it with `javac TheClassName.java` (which produces `TheClassName.class` file in the same dir) I unfortunately can not run it:

```
# java -cp . thepackagename.TheClassName
Error: Could not find or load main class thepackagename.TheClassName
```

Here another try:

```
# export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.91-0.b14.el7_2.x86_64/jre
# $JAVA_HOME/bin/java -cp . thepackagename.TheClassName
Error: Could not find or load main class thepackagename.TheClassName
```

Setting another environment variable does not help either:

```
# export CLASSPATH=.
```

Similar command on Windows 7 works well and I have tried copying the `TheClassName.class` file from there to Linux too.

Please help and please do not suggest marking this question as duplicate, because as you see above, I have already tried most of the suggestions.

The SELINUX is off (`SELINUX=disabled`) and the server was installed few weeks ago, serving (without errors) as LAMP with MySQL/PostgreSQL/Apache/WordPress.

**UPDATE:**

Yes, I had to move the class file under `thepackagename` dir and then it works:

```
# ls thepackagename
TheClassName.class

# java -cp . thepackagename.TheClassName
Hello World!
```

I can even create a `test.jar` file and it still works now:

```
# zip -r test.jar thepackagename
  adding: thepackagename/ (stored 0%)
  adding: thepackagename/TheClassName.class (deflated 31%)

# java -cp test.jar thepackagename.TheClassName
Hello World!
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the class is in a package:

```
package thepackagename;

public class TheClassName {
        public static final void main(String[] args)  {
                System.out.println("Hello World!");
        }
}
```

Then calling it from the wrong directory results in:

```
Error: Could not find or load main class thepackagename.TheClassName
```

It must be called with its fully-qualified name:

```
java -classpath . thepackagename.TheClassName
```

And this command must be called from the **same directory** in which the `thepackagename` directory exists. This means you have to create a new directory called `thepackagename` and move `TheClassName.class` into it, then run the above command from the parent directory of the `thepackagename` directory.

Comment: Oh, you are 100% right and moving the file to `thepackagename/TheClassName.class` helps (and probably makes my question to a duplicate)... However [my real program](https://github.com/afarber/jetty-newbie/tree/master/WebsocketHandler) consisting of few jar-files still does not run. I have to investigate more and will ask a separate question.

Comment: To run Java files with an external jar run `java -cp .:/path/to/jar/file MyCompiledFile`  where you replace `/path/to/jar/file` with the full path to your external .jar file.